# AWS S3 won't redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com, but will redirect http://www.example.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have my website setup on S3 and fronted with CloudFront.  Everything works out well as far as hosting and such is concerned, but I'm having some weird issues when it comes to redirecting `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`.

I've setup the site to be rooted at `example.com`.  I have two S3 buckets, one for the root domain (i.e. `example.com`) and one for `www.example.com`.  The main content is hosted in the `example.com` bucket, while the `www` bucket is empty.

The `www` S3 bucket is setup to redirect all requests to go to the `example.com` domain.  I have cleared the protocol field so that it will match the original request.  The redirect domain just says `example.com`.

The policy for the `www` bucket is pretty basic, but I'm including it here for completeness:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/..."
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.example.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What ends up happening is that I can successfully redirect `http://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`, but `https://www.example.com/`simply hangs.  Checking this out in `curl` just causes a timeout.

On the CloudFront side, I have my CF distribution setup with `example.com` as the alternate domain, and my Origin only points to my `example.com` bucket.

I use Route53 for DNS, and the `www.example.com` A record points to the `www` S3 bucket, while the A record for `example.com` points to the CloudFront distribution.

I'm at a complete loss here and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why `www.example.com` in R53 points to the bucket directly? Your bucket policy only allows OAI user from CF to access it. Thus, direct access (i.e., without CF) shouldn't be possible.

Comment: True, given there's no content to pull down this is a spurious policy, but the re-direction should hit first.  Keep in mind that the policy is for `GetItem`, but as there are no items it should never kick in.  I still need a DNS entry for the `www` site though, so that still stands as being necessary.

Comment: S3 website endpoints do not support HTTPs. So if you just directly go to the bucket s3 website endpoint, there won't be HTTPs, which could explain why your `https://www.example.com` does not work.

Comment: For serving up web content, sure, but why offer the option for matching the protocol for the redirection setting then if they only support `http`?  Something doesn't add up.

Comment: "Amazon **S3 does not support HTTPS** access to the website. If you want to use HTTPS, you can use Amazon CloudFront to serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3. "  from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html#step3-add-bucket-policy-make-content-public). But you wrote that "https://www.example.com/simply hangs". You can't use HTTPs as indicated in the docs. You have to use CF for that. Thus I don't understand why your "www.example.com A record points to the www S3 bucket". It should point to CF, not s3 bucket.

Comment: So I did try using a second CF domain to try to "front" the S3 bucket, but I end up getting HTTP 403 errors on every request because again, there is no content in this `www.example.com` bucket.  I get that S3 doesn't support HTTPS out of the box and that I need to use CF to front it, but why does it offer me the option to select to match on either HTTP or HTTPS for the re-direct option in S3?

Comment: To be clear, I'm referring to step 7 in this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#redirect-endpoint-host

Again, there is no content to serve from this second bucket - it's entire purpose is to re-direct to the other A record, which is behind CF.

Comment: This is generic option. Even if S3 websites don't support https, you may be redirecting to some other hosts, which does support it. But thatnks for the link, now I think start to understand your setup. So in your case you have: `http://www.example.com -> R53 -> S3 bucket -> S3 bucket redirects to https://example.com -> R53 -> CF -> bucket`?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I finally figured this one out.  Thanks to @Marcin for pointing me in the right direction, and to a helpful Reddit user who provided me with a quick Lambda function.

Essentially I had to use a second CloudFront distribution to handle the HTTPS front-end (like @Marcin has mentioned) for the `www.example.com` domain, but that alone did not fix the problem.  The underlying S3 bucket returned a 403 error even though the bucket is configured to only do re-directions.

To get around this I had to create a new Lambda @ Edge function that looked for the `www` prefix in the `Host` header, then do the 301 redirect via the lambda on the second CF instance.  I added this as a Viewer-Request level trigger on the CF distribution, and now everything words as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer in guiding me to resolve the same issue I've encountered with my static website. I would also like to mention that CF now offers a simpler Function feature (or a subset of Lambda) to handle redirects. See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable CloudFront for this bucket [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to access this https://www.example.com/ and point to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) bucket to redirect properly.

Set up CloudFront same as example.com for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it will works.